# Content Include in Kentico CMS

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I'm trying to include an Asset in Kentico CMS (.net), but the include is rendered as plain text on my web page?

Is this the correct syntax?

```
{% IncludeContent("/canada/assets/includes/GlobalMetaBlock.jsp") %}
```

File Path is correct.

Comment: POPEYE1716, first you need to understand that {%  %} is a macro call in Kentico, and there is no existing macro for "IncludeContent". Second, where do you want to include this jsp?

Comment: Thank s for your input Rui, I have placed it in the head of the page